# Android Studio - How to post an HTTP request to Google reverse image search?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-api

I'm currently developing an app to acquire a picture using the phone camera and request some results to the Google reverse image search.

Now, for what I've researched so far Google APIs accepts a picture URL as input to make the reverse search, but I don't have an URL, since it's a picture the user takes in that moment, and I only have the Bitmap.

How can I pass the picture as input to the Google reverse image search using a post HTML request?

I'm using Android Studio and Java.

Here's my code:

```
public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null) {
    Bundle bundle = result.getData().getExtras();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
    
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    //getRequest();
    //postRequest();
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the URL of the taken image?

Comment: @providerZ No, I want to pass the bitmap in the post request. By the way, since you mentioned it, is there a way I can get the URL of the taken image?

Comment: of course,You can get both URL and bitmap, You get the URL first then you convert it to a bitmap that's the normal behavior, Then do whatever you want with the bitmap

Comment: @providerZ Oh, I didn't know I get the url from a picture taken by the camera. How can I do that?

Comment: show me your code , I usually  use a media launcher for that

Comment: @providerZ thank you, I've updated the question including my code

Comment: your approach is already been deprecated by the way, Sure we can do discuss

Comment: @providerZ I texted you

Comment: text me into discord, Chat here is kinda weird to me, Add me provider#2997

Comment: @SKAE is your issue is resolve?

Comment: @Attaullah No it isn't